# SQL Joining Tables in Query

Tags: sql, computer-science

I need to list the `CategoryName`, `ProductID`, `ProductName`, `Unit`, and `Price` with only results from category 3 in SQL Query. I have tried to follow the instructions, but the ones provided are vague. I am using the w3schools website.

I have no idea what the table structure is. But I will give all of the information that was given to me. I have to join two table, `Categories` and `Products`.

The **Categories** consists of the following:

`CategoryID`, `CategoryName`, `Description`

The **Products** consists of the following:

`ProductID`, `ProductName`, `SupplierID`, `CategoryID`, `Unit`, `Price`.

I only need to have the `CategoryName` from `Categories`, the `ProductID`, `ProductName`, `Unit`, and `Price` with all of my results being from Category 3 in Products.

Comment: you need to provide the table structure for people to help you.

Comment: Please provide the table structure

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT cat.CategoryName, prod.ProductID, prod.ProductName, prod.Unit, prod.Price
FROM Categories cat
JOIN products prod
ON cat.CategoryID = prod.CategoryID 
WHERE cat.CategoryID = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks @ Surface Tension! It worked. I had the parts after join correct, but had not originally put Category.CategoryName after select or prod. before everything relating to products. Thanks again. I appreciate it.

Comment: I tried, but I just made an account, so it won't allow me to.

Comment: @SurfaceTension please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/4298200) post on answering homework questions. You didn't provide any help or explanation. Try to give helpful answers rather than answer to just score some easy points

Comment: @SurfaceTension did you just seriously downvote all my answers/questions?!